# Find Kth Smallest Value in BST -- K not changing

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I've mulled over this for so long it's frying my brain. It's possibly I don't fully understand recursion yet.

I don't understand why the value of k, after it equals reaches 0, does not go into the negatives. Instead it remains 0 until the helper function exists. I tried passing in an integer with an initial value of zero and adding until its value equaled k. However, this resulted in the same problem where once it equaled k, it remained that way.

Can someone please explain why the value stays the same?

```
class Solution {
        public int kthSmallest(TreeNode t, int k) {
          TreeNode tempNode = new TreeNode();
          int iter = 0;
          getKValue(t, k, tempNode); 
          return tempNode.val;
        }
        
        private static void getKValue(TreeNode t, int k, TreeNode temp) {
            if(t == null) {
                return;
            }
        
    
            getKValue(t.left, k, temp);
            
            
            k = k - 1;
            System.out.println(k);
            if(k == 0) {
                temp.val = t.val;
                return;
            }
            getKValue(t.right, k, temp);
        
        }
    }
```

For example, for the tree below the expected output is 1. But I get 3 and the console prints 0 twice.

```
Input: root = [3,1,4,null,2], k = 1
   3
  / \
 1   4
  \
   2
Output: 1
```

Comment: Try to debug and follow the execution on a piece of paper and you will know why you are getting 3 and 0 is being printed twice. You are calling the helper function recursively and then doing k = k - 1 which is why you see 0 printed twice. Also the last return will be at node 3 which is why 3 is returned

Comment: @SherifelKhatib -- this is not the case actually. he is getting printed twice because, each time he is calling recursive method, a new copy of K is generating from Left hand side and Right hand side of the tree. He need to send a K which will be common for both LHS and RHS ( that is the case, of call by reference, but unfortunately java don't support call by reference)

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL my reason is from the execution perspective and yours is from the algorithmic one ... same same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are passing `k` across each recursive call. You shouldn't do that because that causes each recursive call to get their own *copy* of `k`. This means that when you modify `k`:

```
k = k - 1;
```

The other calls down the stack does not know about `k` changing. As far as the other calls are concerned, `k` is still 1, because they each have their own copy.

To fix this, you should have one *shared* `k`, that all the recursive calls can access:

```
    static int sharedK; // shared!
    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode t, int k) {
      TreeNode tempNode = new TreeNode();
      sharedK = k; // setting the sharedK
      getKValue(t, tempNode); 
      return tempNode.val;
    }
    
    private static void getKValue(TreeNode t, TreeNode temp) {
        if(t == null) {
            return;
        }

        getKValue(t.left, temp);
        
        sharedK--; // note the change here
        System.out.println(sharedK);
        if(sharedK == 0) {
            temp.val = t.val;
            return;
        }
        getKValue(t.right, temp);
    }
```

The same thing could be achieved if `k` were passed by reference, but unfortunately you can't pass by reference in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem needs you to output the Kth Smallest element of BST, Here is the code which use O(N) memory space, where N is number of nodes in BST. First we will traverse the BST using in-order traversal (recursive) and save the nodes in an array or vector. In-order traversal of BST gives nodes in sorted order.

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
};

vector<int> nodes;

void inorder(TreeNode *root) {
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        nodes.push_back(root->val);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
class Solution {
public:
    int getValue(TreeNode* root,int K)
    {
        nodes.clear();
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
            inorder(root);
            return nodes[K-1];
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```